# iOS Widget multiple deeplinking path using widgetURL

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, deep-linking

I have a .systemMedium widget. There are 2 vstack to navigate to different view in the app (view deep linking)

The problem is when I press the first vstack, it kept on redirecting to the Button2Path instead of Button1Path:

```
var body: some View {

        HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top) {
            Spacer()

            VStack {
                Button {
                    print("button 1 was tapped")
                } label: {
                    Image("BtnView1")
                }
                Text("button 1")
            }.widgetURL(URL(string: "testApp://Button1Path"))

            Spacer()

            VStack {
                Button {
                    print("button 2 was tapped")
                } label: {
                    Image("BtnView2")
                }
                Text("button 2")
            }.widgetURL(URL(string: "testApp://Button2Path"))
        }
 }
```

Check the docs on widgetURL  it says "Sets the URL to open in the containing app when the user clicks the widget."

Are there any other way to achieve this please?

Is it by using Link? how to use it with Vstack?

```
    Link(destination: URL(string: "testApp://Button1Path")!) {
        Text("Link 1")
    }
```

Comment: Able to solve it by wrapping both vstack with different Link respectively

Comment: You should write an answer, worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to open URLs for widgets:

If your widget needs to handle URLs only in one place - you can use     **`widgetURL(_:)`**.
This method returns a view that opens the specified URL when the user clicks the widget.

> Widgets support one widgetURL modifier in their view hierarchy. If
> multiple views have widgetURL modifiers, the behavior is undefined.

```
struct TestWidgetEntryView: View {
var entry: Provider.Entry

var body: some View {
      VStack {
         Text("Hello World!")
         Text("By clicking on widget you open URL in the containing app!")
     }
     .widgetURL(entry.url)
   }
}
```

For widgets that use WidgetFamily.systemMedium or WidgetFamily.systemLarge you can add one or more **Link controls** to your widget’s view hierarchy.

```
struct SimpleWidgetEntryView: View {
var entry: SimpleProvider.Entry

var body: some View {
    Link(destination: URL(string: "myapp://screen1")!) {
        Text("Open Screen 1")
    }
  }
}
```

**You can use both widgetURL and Link controls.** If the interaction targets a Link control, the system uses the URL in that control. For interactions anywhere else in the widget, the system uses the URL specified in the widgetURL view modifier.

To enable handling multiple deeplinks in your example- wrap both VStacks with different Link controls respectively.

```
    var body: some View {

    HStack(alignment: VerticalAlignment.top) {
        Spacer()
        
        Link(destination: URL(string: "testApp://Button1Path")!) {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    print("button 1 was tapped")
                } label: {
                    Image("BtnView1")
                }
                Text("button 1")
            }
        }
        
        Spacer()
        
        Link(destination: URL(string: "testApp://Button2Path")!) {
            VStack {
                Button {
                    print("button 2 was tapped")
                } label: {
                    Image("BtnView2")
                }
                Text("button 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case of having more than one deeplink in the view hierarchy- you use Link controls to handle them.